# Decompressing a base 64 encoded GZip with Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, base64, gzip, gzipstream

I have the following python code which works:

```
import sys
import base64
import gzip
from io import BytesIO

def deserialize(encoded_string): # decode and decompress the base64 string
  compressed_json = base64.b64decode(encoded_string)
  compressedFile = BytesIO()
  compressedFile.write(compressed_json)
  compressedFile.seek(4)

  decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='r')
  decompressed_json = decompressedFile.read()
  return decompressed_json
```

My task is simple and yet, for some reason, daunting...
I need to rewrite the code above so that it would work in Powershell.

So far, I've gotten as far as the following:

```
$input = '<some_base64_encoded_string_here>'    
$b64 = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($input)
$ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream(,$b64)
$gzs = New-Object IO.Compression.GzipStream($ms, [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
$sr = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($gzs, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$decoded = $sr.ReadToEnd();
Write-Host $decoded
```

But I keep getting an error in the line that creates the IO.StreamReader object:

```
Exception calling "ReadToEnd" with "0" argument(s): "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."
At line:6 char:1
+ $decoded = $sr.ReadToEnd();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidDataException
```

I have no idea why this is happening...

The string I'm trying to decode is valid because the same string passes with flying colors in the python script.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Notice the python version skips the first 4 bytes after b64decoding: `compressedFile.seek(4)`. You don't skip anything in the powershell version

Comment: Yes, I suspected this might be it as well. However: The original author of the python script told me that this should not be necessary when using .NET code. And also, I wasn't actually successful in replicating the same behavior in Powershell. It also resulted in an error. @MathiasR.Jessen Do you know how this should be done in Powershell?